# Why willResignActiveNotification called multiple times with Collection view?

Tags: swift, uikit

I'm using PencilKit sample as an example. I added a willResignActiveNotification modification. After you quit move move back and fourth between collectionView and note 3 times.

Then move the app to background, you'll observe willResignActiveNotification active 3 times. I expect to see it called once only. **But why 3 times? Is there a way to avoid it?**

In DrawingViewController class, I have:

```
lazy var willResignActive: (Notification) -> Void = { [weak self] _ in
    print("Saved on willResignActive")
}
```

In viewWillAppear, I have

```
_ = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification,
                                           object: nil,
                                           queue:.main,
                                           using: willResignActive)
```

Here are the sample Xcode. https://github.com/legolasW/DrawingWithPencilKit
To reproduce the result, click the note then back. Repeat.
Then move the app to background, and you'll observe willResignActiveNotification runs multiple times.

The results are like below.
[image]

Edits:

- I tried to move addObserver to viewDidLoad, problem persists.
- I tried to removeObserver in willResignActive closure, problem
  persists.
- I double checked with the memory graph, can confirm its not a
  DrawingViewController memory retain.
- I tried willResignActiveNotification, willResignActiveNotification, willBecomeActiveNotificication, willEnterBackground, showed same multiple call behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Move

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification,
                                       object: nil,
                                       queue:.main,
                                       using: willResignActive)
```

to `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did moved it to viewDidLoad, the problem persists unfortunately. Is there any other way I could try?

Comment: I also added somethings I tried in the edits at the end of the questions. I'm wondering if this is because some concepts I'm missing with the navigation controller or collection view? That caused this multiple calls.

Comment: ok leave observer in `viewWillAppear` and remove it in `viewWillDisappear`

Comment: Nope, tried the already. Problem persists. Even when I add NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self) in viewWillDisappear. It still called multiple times. Is my method fundamentally wrong in some way?

Comment: try to change it to `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,selector.....`

Comment: Works! May I ask if you know why NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.willResig... did not work? It appears when I switch to self,selector.....  everything works as expected.